# TestCafe unable to connect to localhost specified in my hosts file that connects to a DevTest aka Lisa Service Virtualization system

Tags: browser, connection, localhost, virtualization, testcafe

How can I connect to localhost?

Local host is specified in my hosts file like below:
#SSL enabled port: 44323
127.0.0.1   visual.tests.com
127.0.0.1       visual.tests.com/motors

```
    fixture`Motors web page`  
            .page`<https://visual.tests.com:44323/motors?loc=en_NL&requester=ST/>`
```

and I get browser error "http://localhost:51705/about:error"

but I am getting below errors with my attempts:

Failed to load the page at "https://visual.tests.com:44323/?loc=en_NL&requester=ST/".
Increase the value of the "pageRequestTimeout" variable, enable the "retryTestPages" option, or use   quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute this test.
You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at
"https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".

```
  Error details:  
  Error: Failed
```

or
Error details:
Error: SSL certificate error (ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)
or
Error details:
Error: ConnectionRefused
or
Error details:
Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at
"https://visual.tests.com:44323/track?loc=en_NL&requester=ST/".

Expected website to open even to visual.tests.com:44323.
This url connects to a Broadcom aka Lisa Servicer virtualization site that stores data for testing purposes.

Attempts below:
testcafe chrome icod.local.ts --hostname https://visual.tests.com

```
testcafe chrome icod.local.ts --hostname visual.tests.com

testcafe chrome icod.local.ts --hostname visual.tests.com/motors
```

Comment: Is it possible to reach the test page without TestCafe in the same environment?

Comment: Yes I am to connect to environment without testcafe

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had upgraded to TestCafe 3.0 which it will require that you disable the native-automation.

You can also downgrade to older version of TestCafe instead of including option in command line string.

I am able to using the following:
https://visual.tests.com:44323/track?loc=en_NL/ in my fixture.page by including "--disable-native-automation" in my command line test run.

Below is fixture.page used in my test:

```
fixture`Motors web page`  
            .page`https://visual.tests.com:44323/track?loc=en_NL/`
```

Below is the sample command line script that I used successfully.

```
testcafe chrome -e devtest.local.ts --disable-native-automation
```

Additional reading:

https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode#q-how-do-i-disable-native-automation